# Error:(63, 3) type mismatch; found : Unit required: Double

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val Match: (String) => Double = (address: String) => {
    val address =
    if (address == null)
      empty
    else
      Address
}
```

**in this code i m getting this Error**

> > type mismatch;  found   : Unit  required: Double

Comment: the error message is obvious isn't it? your function is not returning anything but you have defined return type as string to double

Comment: can you tell the right code h

Comment: It depends what the function is supposed to do. can you explain that?

Comment: val empty = 0.2 , val Address = 0.0

Comment: You mean to say that if the address in null then return 0.2 else 0.0? is that so?

Comment: yes you are right .

Comment: I hope the answer below is helpful

Comment: the error message is clear.

Answer (score 1):

the return type of the `Match` function is a function which takes a `string` and returns a `double`

```
(String) => Double
```

and you mentioned in the comment

> > val empty = 0.2 , val Address = 0.0

so the correct function definition should be as

```
val Match: (String) => Double = (address: String) => {
   if (address == null)
      empty
    else
      Address
}
```

**the mistakes** were that you didn't return a double value from the function calculated in i`f else` expression and that you used the same variable name as the input argument inside the scope of the function i.e. `val address =`

Alternatively you can use assignment and return that assigned value too

```
val Match: (String) => Double = (address: String) => {
   val addr = if (address == null)
      empty
    else
      Address
  addr
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
val empty = 0.2; val Address = 0.0

val Match: (String) => Double =
 (address:String)=>address match{
 case null => empty
 case _ => Address
 }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> Match(null)
res79: Double = 0.2

scala> Match("")
res80: Double = 0.0

scala> Match("yoohh")
res81: Double = 0.0
```